# Need to Show a complex data structure in eclipse custom view

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I have a created a custom eclipse view through view extension.My requirement is like:

1> I have a datastructre MapData having following attributes:
     MapData
        |-> InputFields (List) 
        |-> OutputFields (List)

2> I need to show above datastructure in the my customize view as below:

```
 + MapData (root element)
```

on clicking + sign following needs to display:

```
 - MapData
    |-> + InputFields
    |-> + OutputField
```

If user click + sign of InputFields, I need to display SWT TableViewer which will display the List of InputFields. Similarly for OutputField. Remember,I can have multiple root element like MapData for other datatypes.

I was looking into eclipse properties view.Do I need to extend that properties view or is there any other good way to implement above usecase.

Any help would be highly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The properties view is just a `TreeViewer` using multiple columns.

Comment: Agreed! What would you suggest to look into for the above use case.

Comment: This just seems like a TreeViewer with a suitable Content Provider.